# Python losing list of objects

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variables, object

When I execute this program I get an empty list:

I am expecting it to create the list of objects and append the objects to the obj_list_addresses list.

Then when I call the get_good_addresses() I expect it to go back through that list and execute code on each object in the list only the list returns empty [] almost like its getting overwritten.

I am fairly new to python and know that I am missing something important.

Main:

```
from address import Address
from address_processor import AddressProcessor
addresses=[]
addresses = open('test.txt').read().splitlines()
proccess_addresses = AddressProcessor(addresses)
proccess_addresses.create_addresses_obj()
proccess_addresses.get_good_addresses()
```

AddressProcessor Class:

```
import multiprocessing
from address import Address

class AddressProcessor(object):
    """AddressProcessor will process a txt file with addresses"""

    def __init__(self, addresses):

        self.addresses = addresses
        self.return_addresses = []
        self.obj_list_addresses = []

    def create_addresses_obj(self):
        jobs = []
        for address in self.addresses:
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=(address,))
            jobs.append(process)
            process.start()
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()
        print('created objects for addresses in text file')

    def worker(self, address):

        obj = Address(address)
        self.obj_list_addresses.append(obj)

    def get_good_addresses(self):

        print self.obj_list_addresses
```

Address Class:

```
from string import replace
from pprint import pprint

class Address(object):

"""
This is address class send it an address it will look up
the addy and return json string of the parcels that matched the address 
then update status if it was the only one returned its good if not its bad
"""

def __init__(self, address):

    self.address = address
    self.status = ''
    self.json_string = ''

    self.set_json_string()

def get_address(self):
    return self.address

def set_json_string(self):

    r = requests.get('urlbasegoeshere'+replace(self.address," ","+")+'&pagesize=40&page=1')
    self.json_string = r.json
    self.set_status()

def set_status(self):

    if len(self.json_string) == 1:
        self.status = 1

    elif len(self.json_string)!=1:
        self.status = 0

def get_status(self):
    return self.status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using 'multiprocessing' to create address objects? Different process don't share memory, i.e. they don't share objects. This is not a python thing, it's the same whatever language you use.

Replace these three lines

```
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=(address,))
        jobs.append(process)
        process.start()
```

with

```
        self.worker(address)
```

Comment: I was setting up multiprocessing trying to learn how it worked. I eventually will be going through each address in the list and doing multiple requests to scrape data and download pdfs for each address. I was hoping to use multiprocessing so that the connections and pdf's would be downloaded in parallel. I will accept your answer and open another later to help with the multiprocessing. Thanks

Comment: @Mrd05d  Database is a better way to do this.

Comment: You are saying that the database would make it easier to store the information instead of trying to use the class variables with multiprocessing?

Comment: Database is a better way for processes to share data. It doesn't make it easier to write the main function of your program - downloading and parsing data. But it's helpful if you want to write a manager to keep track of status and result of each task.

Comment: But if you are not going to download a lot of file. It's easier to use separate text files(json, xml, plain text, etc.) to store information such as download status, address and pdf path. Whenever you want to get an overview or search for a specific item you can traverse all the text files. Later you can load these data into database if size of the project increases too much.

Comment: I am really just trying to make this like a utility to go out and get info write to a text file download pdfs zip the files and send via email... That is why I was thinking about multiprocessing. If there are 50 addresses in the list and each has average of 10 pdfs to download at 5 second wait time each thats a lot of wait time if the connections are done in order. If i could run them simultaneously i can shave off lots of time.